# Not authorized on admin to execute command mongoDB: Atlas M0 Free Tier cluster

Tags: mongodb-3.4, mongodb-3.6, mongodb-atlas

My MongoDB shell has version v3.6.5 (the same with older versions) & MongoDB server has version: 3.6.8

I have MongoDB M0 Free Tier cluster and I want to use from shell different commands.

So, I created admin user with password:
[image]

Set up IP Whitelist:
[image]

And then connect via MongoDB shell using admin user:
[image]

Up to this point, everything is fine, but when I started to use commands I get always the issue:
[image]

I checked the answer from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159472/153538) and tried to create admin user directly from mongodb shell using command, but also the same error:
[image]

Why it happens? If I has already created admin user? Can someone explain me, thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a hosted database service (MongoDB Atlas), many administrative commands are limited as they are either provided via the management interface or likely to introduce performance/stability issues.

The Atlas free tier has additional limitations since it is backed by a shared MongoDB instance. See: [Unsupported Commands in M0/M2/M5 Clusters](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands/).

> "not authorized on admin to execute command {setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: \"3.4\" }"

The [`setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) is an administrative command used during upgrades. You cannot set this on Atlas Free Tier (M0) or shared (M2/M5) clusters.

> db.createUser(...)

User permissions and roles for MongoDB Atlas must be managed via the Atlas user interface or API. See: [Add MongoDB Users](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/).